# KDE Plasma Daemon. I kept being asked for my wifi password

Tags: kde, plasma

I'm using Ubuntu Studio and for some reason my wifi connection is getting deactivated from time to time with a message asking me to give the wifi password again. I type it in and it works ok...until the next time it drops and I am asked for the wifi password again. It seems to happen when I take the laptop into another room where the wifi signal is weaker but not super-weak. Any advice appreciated as always.

Best

Matt

Comment: Do you have perhaps a dual-band (2.4GHz and 5GHz) router with the same name (SSID) for both APs?

Comment: Erm..Quite possibly but I am not sure. It;s stopped happening now. Only seems to happen when I go in the other room. How would I check my router?

Comment: If you use a modern Android phone, particularly the ones running MIUI (Xiaomi) you can easily confirm. Any network with the really-not-recommended setting I mentioned above will show 2.4G/5G right after the name. And you can always open the router settings, of course. I suspect this is the case and your computer is trying its best to roam between both bands - likely using 5G when closer and 2.4G when far apart - and for some reason requesting the password again when toggling. Again, just a suspicion, but something worth checking and changing to the recommended setup with different names...

Comment: ... And make sure it's using at least WPA2-AES, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and no TKIP (old routers will still provided that option but it shouldn't be used because unsafe and deprecated a long time ago).

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: Thank you all for your kind help